# On the principal value of $\ln(1+z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

A complex number $a$ is said to be a logarithm of $c$ if $e^a=c$. It follows that the complex number $w=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}z^n/n$ satisfies $e^w=1+z$. I want to prove that this number $w$ is the principal value of the logarithm. By principal value of $\ln(x)$ we mean the number $\ln|x|+i\arg(x)$ right? There are also other solutions, specifically those obtained by adding $2k\pi i$ for $k$ integer. Now I want to prove, if I'm not wrong, that $k$ is zero? How can I do it formally? For example, if $z=0$ then $w=0=\ln(1+0)$ implies I think $k=0$. But for all the other values of $z$? Thank you! I'm new to this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Principal logarithm, usually denoted by $Log \,z$, is an  analytic function on $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$. In particular it is analytic in the open disk of radius $1$ around $1$. So $Log (1+z)$ has power series expansion around $0$. The successive deriavtives of $Log (1+z)$ are $\frac {(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!} {(1+z)^{n}}$ so the power series becomes exactly the one you have.

Comment: If we take instead the derivatives of $\ln(1+z)$ (not principal) wouldn't we get the same derivatives?

Comment: @justadude The crucial fact is the series vanishes at $0$. The principal logarithm of $1$ is $0$ but $2k\pi i$ are all logarithms of $1$.

Comment: Yes I understand that...but I don't understand why it holds for other values of $z$...

Comment: The power series of $f$ starts with $f(0)$. (This is crucial).  The value of $Log (1+z)$ is $0$ only for the principal logarithm. You have add $2\pi ik$ to get all $w$ such that $e^{w}=1+z$. @justadude

Comment: So basically for other values of the logarithm we would have $2k\pi i$ in front of the series?

Comment: @justadude Exactly. That is the only difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it's clear!